# store SQL variable from INSERT query FROM clause result column

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, insert, declare

This is probably trivial to most of you, but I haven't been writing stored procedures for very long (6 months only).  I'd like to be able to set the variable @testid based on one of the columns being used for an INSERT query.  How can I do this?

```
DECLARE @testid INT;

INSERT INTO [exporttestresultreport] (
    [testid],
    [othercolumn]
) 
SELECT
    [testid],  -- <======= how can I set my variable based on this column?
    [othercolumn]
FROM 
    [exporttestresultreport] e
WHERE 
    [exporttestresultreportid] = @exporttestresultreportid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @testid INT;

DECLARE @test TABLE (testid int);

INSERT INTO [exporttestresultreport] (
    [testid],
    [othercolumn]
) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.testID INTO @test
SELECT
    [testid],  -- <======= how can I set my variable based on this column?
    [othercolumn]
FROM 
    [exporttestresultreport] e
WHERE 
    [exporttestresultreportid] = @exporttestresultreportid;

SELECT @testid = testid FROM @test;
```

An INSERT..SELECT.. is inherently multirow so it doesn't make semse to allow assigning a value to a scalar variable: what row should be used for the value?

Comment: If you correct your syntax I will mark it as the answer.  That's why I chose the other fella's.  How can I combine those queries?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @testid INT;

DECLARE @t TABLE(t INT);

INSERT exporttestresultreport
(
    testid, othercolumn
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.testid INTO @t
SELECT testid, othercolumn 
FROM 
    [exporttestresultreport] e
WHERE 
    [exporttestresultreportid] = @exporttestresultreportid;

SELECT @testid = t FROM @t;

-- not sure what you want to do if there are multiple rows in the insert
```

Comment: Do you know how I can add multiple temp tables in the same OUTPUT line?

Comment: Sure, you can add more columns to @t and then add , INSERTED.othercolumn to the OUTPUT clause. But if your intention is to output ALL of the columns into variables, then why not just `SELECT @testid = testid, @othercolumn = othercolumn FROM ...; INSERT exporttestresultreport SELECT @testid, @othercolumn;`?